# Y-axis of a seaborn distribution

Tags: python, seaborn, distribution

I would like to change the y-axis of this plot. I don't know why I'm getting such low probabilities.

The code I have is just:

```
sns.distplot(df, kde=True);
```

And df is the following one:

```
salaries
0   848
1   950
2   1577
3   963
4   1054
5   1013
6   985
7   1513
8   1021
9   895
10  983
11  1290
12  1043
13  881
14  924
15  1040
16  975
17  1183
18  1100
19  879
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of a density function (which is what a histogram approximates) is not probability.  Probabilities are found as the area under the density, and the total area must be 1.  Given the range of your x-axis, you shouldn't be surprised that the heights along the y-axis are small—the average height should be about 1/800 (a.k.a. 0.00125) to yield an area of 1, which looks very much like what you're getting.